# Photos are being swapped between both iphones

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, photos, data-transfer

I had iphone4 which I sent overseas to a friend. And I purchased iphone5 which I am using. Just lately I've been getting his photos that he takes and photos which I take of my family are going to his "gallery". I am not sure why but pls help. I need to know why this is happening and what I can do to stop this.

Comment: Did you reset and cleanup iphone4 before sending? Looks like he uses your icloud account and you are getting these photos via Photo Stream. In this case your friend needs to switch to his own account in iCloud settings.

Answer (score 1):

When you sent your iPhone 4 to your friend, the device was not properly wiped first. As a result, all of your accounts are most likely still signed in on his device.

The best recommendation is to completely erase the device. To do this instruct your friend to go to **Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings**. This will wipe the phone and restore it to factory settings. Your friend can then proceed through setup and plug in his own accounts.

If your friend is not willing to wipe the entire device, I recommend he signs out of all of your accounts. He will want to go to all of the following places to do so:

- Settings > iCloud
- Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars
- Settings > Messages
- Settings > FaceTime
- Settings > iTunes & App Stores
- Settings > Music

You may also have apps that were left installed on your iPhone with your account signed in as well (Facebook and Twitter, for example), that you may want to also check.